# NSMutableArray removeLastObject Exception

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, exception, nsmutablearray

According to the [NSMutableArray documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> `removeLastObject` raises an `NSRangeException` if there are no objects in the array.

For some reason, I seem to be able to call this method on an empty array, and no exception is thrown.

Here's a test case:

```
- (void)testNSMutableArray
{
    NSMutableArray* arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    STAssertTrue([arr count] == 0, @"Array count should be 0");
    STAssertThrows([arr removeLastObject], @"Should throw NSRangeException");
}
```

This test case fails on the last line for me with the message:

> [arr removeLastObject] raised (null). Should throw NSRangeException

Am I confused here? Is the documentation wrong?

Comment: I guess it's wrong...the only thing I can think of is that the array is nil, but clearly you have initialized it.

Comment: File a doc bug: https://bugreport.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/RadarWeb.woa/wa/signIn

Comment: Thanks, I've filed a doc bug now that Jesse confirmed below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the assembly, it appears this behaviour changed in Lion. Here's a portion of the implementation of `[__NSArrayM removeLastObject]` (which is the actual implementation you're calling):

```
0x3494975a:  movs   r0, #7
0x3494975c:  bl     0x3490c26c                ; _CFExecutableLinkedOnOrAfter
0x34949760:  cbz    r0, 0x3494977c            ; -[__NSArrayM removeLastObject] + 60
```

This calls `CFExecutableLinkedOnOrAfter` with a value of 7; if that returns 1 (which it does on my machine), you get the behaviour you're seeing. If it returns 0, you get an exception.

`CFExecutableLinkedOnOrAfter` is an undocumented function, but some [snooping around](http://www.gnu-darwin.org/www001/src/DarwinSourceArchive/expanded/CF/CF-368/Base.subproj/CFUtilities.c) suggests that it returns if the executable is linked after a particular version of Mac OS X. Some [more snooping](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-476.14/CFPriv.h?txt) suggests that the value of 7 corresponds to 10.7.

So, if you're running Lion or later, you won't get an exception. Sounds like a doc bug to me!

Comment: God bless you for doing the research

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the documentation seems wrong (or probably outdated) in this case. NSRangeException is thrown when we try to access an object at some index i, which is not present in the array. But in [arr removeLastObject], I guess iOS is automatically checking to ignore the case when the array is empty

Comment: This makes sense, just like `-[NSArray lastObject]` returns `nil` instead of throwing an exception if the array is empty.  Seems like the documentation is just wrong.